# Wrapper struct for Hashmap Mutex Rust

Tags: rust

Say we want to create a wrapper struct for our `Mutex<HashMap<i32, String>>`:

```rust
use std::{sync::{Mutex}};
use std::collections::HashMap;

pub struct HashmapWrapper(Mutex<HashMap<i32, String>>);
impl HashmapWrapper{
    pub fn new()->Self{
        HashmapWrapper(Mutex::new(HashMap::new()))
    }
    pub fn get(&self, id: i32)->Option<&String>{
        self.0.lock().unwrap().get(&id)
    }
    pub fn get_mut(&mut self, id: i32)->Option<&mut String>{
        self.0.lock().unwrap().get_mut(&id)
    }
    pub fn insert(&mut self, id: i32, value: String){
        self.0.lock().unwrap().insert(id, value.clone());
    }
    
}
```

The problem is that various `HashMap` functions values are owned by the current function, and thus cannot be returned:

```
error[E0515]: cannot return value referencing temporary value
  --> src\dropable_manager.rs:36:10
   |
36 |          self.0.lock().unwrap().get_mut(&id)
   |          ----------------------^^^^^^^^^^^^^
   |          |
   |          returns a value referencing data owned by the current function
   |          temporary value created here
```

What would a work around for this be?

Comment: Accept a closure to work on the data and call that with the locked data. You can follow example of Iterator's map function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Gurwinder Singh pointed out, you could implement this in terms of closures, maybe like this:

```rust
use std::collections::HashMap;
use std::sync::Mutex;

pub struct HashmapWrapper(Mutex<HashMap<i32, String>>);
impl HashmapWrapper {
    pub fn new() -> Self {
        HashmapWrapper(Mutex::new(HashMap::new()))
    }
    
    pub fn map<R>(&self, id: i32, f: impl FnOnce(&String) -> R) -> Option<R> {
        self.0.lock().unwrap().get(&id).map(f)
    }

    pub fn map_mut<R>(&mut self, id: i32, f: impl FnOnce(&mut String) -> R) -> Option<R> {
        self.0.lock().unwrap().get_mut(&id).map(f)
    }

    pub fn insert(&mut self, id: i32, value: String) {
        // You're taking `value` by value here, so you don't need to clone it.
        self.0.lock().unwrap().insert(id, value/*.clone()*/);
    }
}
```

and use it like this:

```rust
fn main() {
    let mut w = HashmapWrapper::new();
    w.insert(42, String::from("hello world"));
    assert_eq!(w.map(42, |s| s.len()), Some(11));
    w.map_mut(42, |s| s.push('!'));
    assert_eq!(w.map(42, |s| s.len()), Some(12));
    assert_eq!(w.map(42, |s| s.clone()), Some(String::from("hello world!")));
}
```

What you of course still can't do is this:

```rust
fn main() {
    let mut w = HashmapWrapper::new();
    w.insert(42, String::from("hello world"));
    w.map_mut(42, |s| s.push('!'));
    assert_eq!(w.map(42, |s| s), Some(&String::from("hello world!")));
}
```

That is, just return the reference to a value inside the HashMap from the closure. This is because the reference's lifetime is tied to the lifetime of the `MutexGuard` that it's borrowed from. That `MutexGuard` is dropped at the end of the function call and so no reference borrowed from it can be returned from that function.